# Cannot send push notifications from AWS SNS to my iPad

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

I'm struggle since 2 days to make push notifications from amazon sns to work on my ipad. After nights spending on google and youtube  i'm desperated and the amazon documentation isn't really helpful.

What i already did until now :

I got the certificate from apple and successfully uploaded the .p12 file to SNS and created the application platform and set the endpoint.

I set my cognito credentials in the viewcontroller in xcode and add some notification listeners in the appdelegate.

So When i run the app on the iPad, this one successfully display the deviceToken in the xcode promp. So i can enter it in SNS console and configure it.

So i created all required stuffs (certificate, .p12, registering the devicetoken etc.)

Unfortunately, when i'm trying to publish to the endpoint (send a notification to my device), i never received any notifications. I don't really know what's going bad. Yet, when i'm trying to do the same by sending a push to an email, its works perfectly.

I watched tons of tutorial in youtube and followed several docs on the web but it seems to definitely not working.

In Xcode i didn't forget to enter the same bundle ID than in my apple developer account (com.XXX.XXX), so i think my app is well configured.

Amazon docs are not dev friendly, most tutorial on the web are outdated,

Is someone know the perfect procedure to send push notifications from Amazon SNS to an Ipad ?

Thank you.

Comment: Answer following questions. 1) Are you using Development/Distribution Profile to run your application? 2) Are you using Dev/Dist certificate .p12 for Amazon SNS? 3) What is your payload? 4) Which PushNotificaiton delegate method you have implemented in `AppDelegate.m` file? based on this one can figure out problem

Comment: 1)I used both dev/distribution profile in my tests but none of them worked. 2) Same thing for p12 i tried for both prod/dev in sns, 3) .Alert, .Badge, .Sound 4) in my app delegate i put : application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions, didRegisterUserNotificationSettings, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError and didReceiveRemoteNotification.

Comment: you can test your push notification [here online](apns-gcm.bryantan.info). You just need to create .pem file from .p12 using following terminal command `openssl pkcs12 -in path.p12 -out newfile.pem` [more detail here](http://cc.in2p3.fr/docenligne/84/en). Verify APNS with  Dev/Dist both certificates. If it works well, you have prob in Amazon SNS, else you are doing something wrong with ur Certificate or Profile

Comment: Hi, I would suggest you try out AWS Mobile Hub : https://aws.amazon.com/mobile/ 
It will help you create a starter app which demonstrates push notifications.

Comment: Thanks all for replying. I finally solved the problem. @Dipen the website made me found out what was going wrong . In fact the certificate was not good. something went bad when i generated it from keychain access i was all this time exporting the bad certificate so when i found the right one finally i could send many push notification to my app from amazon SNS. Now everything looks good. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Last night I have successfully integrated AWS SNS.
Yes, the document on AWS are not well documented.

To integrate SNS you need to configure APNS perfectly. I would like to suggest here to first configure all the necessary credentials to get a notification using APNS.
I am expecting here that the developer knows how to create App ID, .p12, .pem and provisioning profile for APNs. Once you successfully get the notification on your device using APNs then you are ready for SNS in quick time. To test the APNs notification you can use this server "www.pushtry.com".

Once everything is successfully done with APNS then jump into your AWS account >> navigate SNS dashboard >> Create platform application.

[image]

After hitting Create Application a form will open to mention your application data and some credential entry of certificate.
Please see the below image to follow the steps.
Password entry is optional as per your .p12 certificate. 
On press "Load credential from file", Certificate and Private Key entry should fill automatically.

[image]

After hitting "Create Platform Application" navigate into application left pane to see the list of created application.

Now you need to create end point.
see the attached image.
[image]

Now fill the End point entry, follow the image below.

[image]

Now copy the Endpoint ARN to use into AWS console to push the message on your device. The Endpoint is actually an address of your device like token in APNS for AWS. Be sure you copied endpoint completely.

[image]

Now again jump into the "SNS Dashboard" to publish the message.

[image]

Now paste your copied "Endpoint ARN" and your text message in this form and hit "Publish Message" as per below image.
Here you are done check your device to get the notification.

[image]

**=================================================================**

**Above I have explained to push the notification through AWS SNS console.**

**Now let me add here code to create Application and Endpoint ARN.**

```
+ (void) initAWSObjectToAccessAccount
{
    // Initialize the Amazon Cognito credentials provider.    
    AWSStaticCredentialsProvider* credentialsProvider = [AWSStaticCredentialsProvider
                                                         credentialsWithAccessKey:kAWSAccessKey
                                                         secretKey:kAWSSecretKey];

    AWSServiceConfiguration* configuration = [AWSServiceConfiguration configurationWithRegion:AWSRegionUSWest2
                                                                          credentialsProvider:credentialsProvider];

    [AWSServiceManager defaultServiceManager].defaultServiceConfiguration = configuration;
}


+ (void) createApplicationAndGetAppARN: (void (^) (BOOL isCreated, NSString* appARN))completion
{
    [self initAWSObjectToAccessAccount];

    NSMutableDictionary *myDictionary = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    [myDictionary setObject:kCertificateSecretKey forKey:@"PlatformPrincipal"];
    [myDictionary setObject:kCertificatePrivateKey forKey:@"PlatformCredential"];

    /* End Amazon SNS Mobile Push self registration */
    AWSSNSCreatePlatformApplicationInput* platFormAppInput = [AWSSNSCreatePlatformApplicationInput new];
    platFormAppInput.name = @"nFormIOS";
    platFormAppInput.platform = @"APNS";            // When Release
    //platFormAppInput.platform = @"APNS_SANDBOX";  // When Development phase
    platFormAppInput.attributes = myDictionary;

    AWSSNS *snsManager = [AWSSNS defaultSNS];
    [[[snsManager createPlatformApplication:platFormAppInput] continueWithBlock:^id(BFTask *task) {

        if (task.error)
        {
            completion (NO, nil);
        }
        else
        {
            AWSSNSCreatePlatformApplicationResponse* appResponse = task.result;
            NSString* applicationARN = appResponse.platformApplicationArn;
            completion (YES, applicationARN);
        }

        return nil;

    }] waitUntilFinished];
}

+ (void) createSNSEndPoint:(NSString*)applicationARN
                completion:(void (^)(BOOL isSuccess, NSString* endpointARN))completion
{
    /* This is the code to actually register the device with Amazon SNS Mobile Push based on the token received. */    
    AWSSNSCreatePlatformEndpointInput* platformEndpointRequest = [AWSSNSCreatePlatformEndpointInput new];
    platformEndpointRequest.customUserData = kUniqueID;     // It could be anything.
    platformEndpointRequest.token = kDeviceTokenNo;         // Device Token No for APNS
    platformEndpointRequest.platformApplicationArn = applicationARN;

    AWSSNS* snsManager = [AWSSNS defaultSNS];

    [[[snsManager createPlatformEndpoint:platformEndpointRequest] continueWithBlock:^id(BFTask *task) {

        if (task.error)
        {
            completion (NO, nil);
        }
        else
        {
            AWSSNSCreateEndpointResponse* endPointRes = task.result;
            completion (YES, endPointRes.endpointArn);
        }

        return nil;
    }] waitUntilFinished];
}
```

**===========================**

**kAWSAccessKey
kAWSSecretKey**

This you will get when you will create a credential in AWS account.

**kCertificateSecretKey
kCertificatePrivateKey**

To get these two follow the steps.

/* STEP 1: Retrieve the SSL certificate (.cer file)

STEP 2: use the following command to convert it into .pem
openssl x509 -in aps.cer -inform DER -out myapnsappcert.pem

STEP 3: Open the file in NotePad. Copy the portion bounded as follows: 
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
-----END CERTIFICATE-----

STEP 4: Use it as NSString replacing the special characters (newlines) with escape sequences (\n). It would now resemble this:

-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----\nMIIGKTCCBRGgAwIBAgIILZH6mrSmUj8wDQYJKoZIhvcNAQELBQAwgZYxCzAJBgNV\n......\n----END CERTIFICATE-----

STEP 5: Save the .cer file as .p12

STEP 6: Use the following command to get the Private Key:
openssl pkcs12 -in CertificatesSNS.p12 -out myapnsappp
rivatekey.pem -nodes -clcerts

STEP 7: Open the file in NotePad. Copy the portion bounded as follows:

-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----
-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----

STEP 8: Repeat Step 4 for this too.

STEP 9: Use the Value retrieved in step4 as "PlatformPrincipal"

STEP 10: Use the Value retrieved in step5 as "PlatformCredential" */